# Не заходит на host/Munin

Tags: debian, munin

Пытаюсь установить мониторинг сервера Munin. Все этапы по различным гайдам завершаю успешно. С удалённого сервера на  192.168.*.*/munin не заходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфиги:

/etc/munin/munin.conf

```
[localhost]
    address 127.0.0.1
    use_node_name yes

[samwms]
address 192.168.*.*
use_node_name yes

allow ^127.0.0.1$
allow ^192.168.#.#$ -- адрес, с которого подключаюсь



cidr_allow 127.0.0.1/32
cidr_allow 192.0.2.0/24
```

munin-node.conf

```
  #
    # Example config-file for munin-node
    #

    log_level 4
    log_file /var/log/munin/munin-node.log
    pid_file /var/run/munin/munin-node.pid

    background 1
    setsid 1

    user root
    group root

    # This is the timeout for the whole transaction.
    # Units are in sec. Default is 15 min
    #
    # global_timeout 900

    # This is the timeout for each plugin.
    # Units are in sec. Default is 1 min
    #
    # timeout 60

    # Regexps for files to ignore
    ignore_file [\#~]$
    ignore_file DEADJOE$
    ignore_file \.bak$
    ignore_file %$
    ignore_file \.dpkg-(tmp|new|old|dist)$
    ignore_file \.rpm(save|new)$
    ignore_file \.pod$

    # Set this if the client doesn't report the correct hostname when
    # telnetting to localhost, port 4949
    #
    host_name pve

    # A list of addresses that are allowed to connect.  This must be a
    # regular expression, since Net::Server does not understand CIDR-style
    # network notation unless the perl module Net::CIDR is installed.  You
    # may repeat the allow line as many times as you'd like

    allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
    allow ^::1$
    allow ^192\.168\.*\.*$ -- адрес, откуда пытаюсь подключиться

    # If you have installed the Net::CIDR perl module, you can use one or more
    # cidr_allow and cidr_deny address/mask patterns.  A connecting client must
    # match any cidr_allow, and not match any cidr_deny.  Note that a netmask
    # *must* be provided, even if it's /32
    #
    # Example:
    #
     cidr_allow 127.0.0.1/32
     cidr_allow 192.0.2.0/24
     cidr_allow 192.168.*.*/32 -- адрес, откуда пытаюсь подключаться
    # cidr_deny  192.0.2.42/32
    # Which address to bind to;
    host *
    # host 127.0.0.1

    # And which port
    port 4949
```

Comment: А апач-то кто-нибудь настраивал?

Comment: Нет. Какие настройки требуются?

Comment: Очевидно, прописать, по какому адресу из какого каталога апач должен отдавать html-файлы мунина. Неужели в гайдах это не описывалось?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Посмотрю настройки апач, спасибо.